# Backbone and jQuery Mobile App resetting after browser back button

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, href

I am building an app using Backbone.js and jQuery Mobile. On some pages in my app I have external href links and I'm running into an issue.

When a user clicks and external href link, get taken to the external site and then hits the back button. My app does not load from the proper page where the user originally left the app from.

In fact my entire DOM is reset so it looks like my site gets a complete refresh and doesn't keep any of its former state.

I have been trying to search for a solution but this issue is kind of hard to word out. I hope it makes sense.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

UPDATE
Stupid error on my part.. I had a bad id set on the page and it didn't load the data I had saved in the session for it when a user returns to the page.. Changed the id and all is well. Thanks!

Comment: You could use Backbone.Router http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="www.external.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Make you external links open up new tabs.

Comment: This solution doesn't work as well for me since this will be a mobile app packaged with PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

If you have used one html with multiple pages solution then there's an explanation for this.

rel="external" will cause a full page refresh so last page location will not be remebered. When you return to the last location it will trigger new refresh and the first page will be shown again.

This can be prevented with a multiple html page solution.

Comment: This is a one html file multi page setup. However when I built this exact same app without backbone with just jquery, clicking back after visiting an external link performed the correct action. I would really like to stick to one html file.